# Dapper exige escrever código SQL, por que?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql, dapper

Estou olhando o seguinte link que usa Dapper: [Getting Started With PostgreSQL Using Dapper In .NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-postgresql-using-dapper-in-net-core/) e a minha duvida é, quando faço pelo Java não preciso escrever o código SQL como esse exemplo aqui:

```
//1. Insert  
using (var conn = OpenConnection(_connStr))  
{  
    var insertSQL = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO public.customer(firstname, lastname, email,createtime)                    
    VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}','{3}');", "Catcher", "Wong", "catcher_hwq@outlook.com", DateTime.Now);  
    var res = conn.Execute(insertSQL);  
    Console.WriteLine(res > 0 ? "insert successfully!" : "insert failure");  
    PrintData();  
}
```

Por esse exemplo eu realmente preciso fazer isso? se precisar qual a vantagem de usar ele?

Comment: Não entendi o que o Java tem a ver com isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por que o Dapper foi criado assim, as tecnologias tem suas características próprias, seja para atender uma demanda que exige que seja assim, seja por vontade de quem a criou, seja por deficiência.

O Dapper tem como objetivo acessar o banco de dados e gerar um objeto para consumo na sua aplicação e praticamente mais nada. Comparar com outra tecnologia não faz sentido porque outra provavelmente tem outro objetivo. Por exemplo o [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) permite fazer de outra forma.

Note que o código usado é bem ruim e inseguro. Eu não seguiria esse tutorial. Tem um próximo do que pode se chamar de oficial muito melhor. [Veja o `Execute()`](http://dapper-tutorial.net/execute). Elias eu não sugeriria tutorial algum, eu procuraria entender como tudo funciona e porquê das coisas, assim pode tomar decisões mais apropriadas.

Como pode ser visto no mesmo site é possível usar um [extensão que evita escrever o SQL para o `INSERT`](http://dapper-tutorial.net/insert) (com vantagens e desvantagens).

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a resposta do Maniero, o seu código é perigoso porque você está concatenando os valores na string e fica sujeito a um SQL Injection.

Segue um exemplo simples de insert com o Dapper

```
// Insert
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    const string sql = @"INSERT INTO [Region] (Name) VALUES (@Name)";

    db.Execute(sql, new { Name = region.Name }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
}
```

Tem uma extensão para o VisualStudio que eu criei para facilitar a vida em alguns projetos:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thiagoguaru.DapperCrudGenerator

Porém para o uso dessa extensão você tem que criar os seus Models, se quiser saber um pouco mais sobre o que é Model já que está iniciando:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-model